# http to https using htaccess leaves site menu without dropdowns

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite

I have added an SSL certificate to my site on WordPress. When I added the following code to the htaccess file I lost the dropdowns in my navigation menu and different things happened in various browsers.

Here's the code I added to htacces to force site from http to https:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

RewriteRule ^.*$ https://{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

So here is what the htaccess file looks like now:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
```

I would appreciate any assistance to get the menu navigation at the top of the site to work again.

Comment: Possibly your menu is linked with `http://` and needs to be `https://`?

Comment: Does this happen across all browsers? Most likely your menu is referenced via http protocol, but when you request the site through https...you get a security clash of insecure (http) items being referenced on an https protocol. For example, if you're including a menu via JavaScript using this: http://www.example.com, try using a protocol agnostic format: //www.example.com so it'll work on both https and http.

Comment: @user2150689 Have you [changed the site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) to use the HTTPS protocol? I also recommend that you mvoe the https rewrite rule *above* the `RewriteBase` directive, it just feels wrong:)

Comment: That would be *below* not above lol

Comment: Hi and thank you for the comments. I changed the site url from http to https. @LookitsPuck where do you go to fix the javascript to make it agnostic...I'm a novice at this.

Comment: Hi and thank you for the comments. I changed the site url from http to https. Still doesn't fix nav issue. @LookitsPuck where do you go to fix the javascript to make it agnostic...I'm a novice at this. This is happening across only across IE and Chrome. IE will let you on the site and then at the bottom has a box to click allow non-secure items..if you click the button then the nav menu dropdown will work. In Chrome, the nav menu doesn't work and the browser bar always shows a broken lock. Firefox seems to be alright and safari seems to be ok also.

Comment: The menus (and associated js code) are likely hard-coded with http, and that is why you can't get them to work on an https connection. Where to go to fix it varies by theme. You could install [WP Debug Objects](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-objects/) and see what scripts are being loaded, or browse through the js folder in the theme to see if you can find where it is loading and you will find an http in there. What theme is this? Can I take a look for you?

Answer (score 0):

Many areas in WordPress create links to content and references as relative (site independent)

```
<a href="/mypage">like this</a>
```

However other places in the code are site specific and reference the full URL.
If you upload an image (for example) it will be referenced at 
http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/image1.jpg

If you search the database tables for http://www.example.com/ and replace it with just / that will make all your references relative and the http/https issue should go away. Be sure to backup your database before

Note too that this will solve the problem of getting a warning in Internet Explorer like this:

> This page contains both secure and nonsecure items.
>   Do you want to display the nonsecure items?

Hope that helps